# Does WPF have a set of default binding converters available?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, ivalueconverter, imultivalueconverter

When creating WPF user controls I often find myself creating small converter classes when binding values.

Often you need to do similar conversions, and it made me wonder whether I might be missing some existing available implementations.

- Does the .NET library contain any implementations of [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) or [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx)?
- Has there been any attempt made to create a library of reusable value converters?

Comment: I just found [WPF Converters](http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com/). But I'm still interested in question 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not many built-in, public are:

- [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx)
- [`AlternationConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.alternationconverter.aspx)
- [`ZoomPercentageConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.zoompercentageconverter.aspx)
- [`JournalEntryListConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.journalentrylistconverter.aspx)

May have missed some...

Comment: Thanks, might I ask how you know this?

Comment: @StevenJeuris: The one i mentioned is the only one that ever sees much use though...

Comment: Okay thanks, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a ****load of classes I could have been using. You answered my questions sufficiently. When I have spare time it might be fun to write code which queries the entire library for classes which implement any of those interfaces. :)

Comment: @StevenJeuris: There are already applications which do that, e.g. [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) which is mainly a decompiler also shows derived types. I just used that to check for the public converters in the .NET assemblies, as mentioned in the answer i may have missed some.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: The Microsoft.Expression.Framework assembly contains a lot of converters, don't know if that is included in the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801) though, if so it might be worth a look.