# List of default converters used by WPF?

Tags: wpf, converters

Where can one find a list of default converters for WPF?

---

After looking into Google, I couldn't find any detailed list of what is actually included in WPF, particularly the MSDN docs. Only found:

- [Does WPF have a set of default binding converters available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560329/does-wpf-have-a-set-of-default-binding-converters-available)
- some articles on `TypeConverter`.

Comment: I've always wondered about same thing and never could find an answer! thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In System.Windows.Control (PresentationFramework.dll)

- AlternationConverter
- BooleanToVisibilityConverter
- BorderGapMaskConverter
- DataGridLengthConverter
- MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter

In System.Windows.Documents

- ZoomPercentageConverter
- JournalEntryListConverter

In Microsoft.Windows.Themes

- ProgressBarBrushConverter
- ProgressBarHighlightConverter

In System.Windows.Navigation

- JournalEntryUnifiedViewConverter

Comment: Thanks, but do you have a source link? I just would like to be sure that there is no other converter hanging around without being caught =)

Comment: Actually I just used Reflector and checked for IValueConverter implementations ;) That's all I found. I'm currently checking again to see if I didnt forget anyone ;)

Comment: Edit : ok I triple checked, that's everything present in the .NET 4.0 framework.

Comment: Nice stuff! Just out of curiosity, do you know if some converters were added to .NET 4.5 ?

Comment: Let me check. Please consider flaggin as answer if you are satisfied with the list :) - Edit : NOthing new in .NET4.5 !

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you! Will keep that as a bookmark. So overall we can say that the included converters are... not that useful. A basic string to double convertor would've been obvious imho

Comment: Many thanks. Goodness only knows why Microsoft don't feel this is something that deserves to be documented more clearly!

Comment: @Damascus: _"A basic string to double convertor would've been obvious"_ -- since WPF already automatically handles bindings between `string` and `double`, how would a converter help?

Comment: A basic cast float to integer would have been nice as well